# What method gets called when I change a value in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a persistent dictionary by wrapping the type `dict` and by especially overloading `__setitem__` to write the values to a file.

```py
class PersistentStorage(dict):
    def __init__(self, file_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.path = file_name

    def write_dict(self):
        with open(self.path, "w") as f:
            json.dump(self, f)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key,value)
        self.write_dict() # writes 'self' to a json file.
```

This works as expected, as long as I don't work with nested dictionaries:

```py
tester = PersistenStorage("example_path.json")

tester["key1"] = "Value for key 1"
# works and gets saved
tester["key2"] = {"subkey":""}
# works as well
tester["key2"]["subkey"] = "Added value"
# works locally but is not written to file (__setitem__ is not called)
```

I tried overloading other methods of the class as well but I can't seem to find the one that gets called in this scenario. I also don't understand why `__setitem__` isn't called.

I also looked into `typing` and `collections` but it seems to me that directly using `dict` as a template class is the best choice, as I don't want to change the inherent functioning of the type, but just expand the reads and writes.

Comment: You are using a normal dict as vallue for `key2` not your class.

Comment: Yes, but why is this a problem? In the end I'm still changing an item from my class, which should trigger `__setitem__`, don't I?

Comment: The last line of code does not set `tester["key2"]`, so no, `__setitem__` is not called.

Comment: @RemyMoll no **you aren't changing an item from your class**. You are *accessing an item from you class*, which will call `__getitem__`. That expression `tester["key"]` gets evaluated to a normal `dict` object, at which point, `__setitem__` is called *on that*

Comment: Ok, is that the issue that shelve is fixing, when setting `writeback = True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling this code:

```
tester["key2"]["subkey"] = "Added value"
```

is equivalent to the following two lines:

```
key2_value = tester["key2"]
key2_value["subkey"] = "Added value"
```

In the first line, `PersistentStorage.__getitem__` is called (because `tester` is a `PersistentStorage`)

In the second line, `dict.__setitem__` is called (because `key2_value` is a `dict`).

If you want to override that setter, you should not use a "normal" `dict` as `tester["key2"]`.

You could, for example, change this line:

```
tester["key2"] = {"subkey":""}
```

to this:

```
tester["key2"] = MyDictWithOverridden_setitem({"subkey":""})
```

And then implement `MyDictWithOverridden_setitem`, or whatever you call it as e.g.

```
class MyDictWithOverridden_setitem(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        do_something_special()
```

Comment: So I take it my hopes of an easy drop-in solution just vanished. I do see my mistake, thank you. I still can't wrap my head around why it happens though: how is a dictionary handled on a memory-level then? If changing values in the nested one does not affect the first one, then they would be distinct entities and they are just symbolically linked?

Comment: @RemyMoll dictionary keys and values are `object`s. `dict` has some requirements on the keys, to be able to handle them efficiently, but it knows nothing and cares not at all about what data is in the values. On the memory-level, if we are talking about CPython, references to values are `PyObject *`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you want by putting logic on your `__setitem__` that converts `{"subkey":""}` to the type you want.

This might involve changing the way your class stores the data, to correctly recreate the nested dict struct.

In other words:

```
tester["key2"] = {"subkey":""}
```

That line would convert the nested dict to `PersistentStorage` and you would keep a reference to the **parent** on that, so you can traverse the tree.